# Is there a way for someone to open a file that will change their background?

Tags: windows-7, images, desktop-customization

This is part of an office prank where we change each other's backgrounds when we forget to lock our computer and we walk away (for security reasons of course) and one of our co-workers has been ruthless and has never walked away and left his computer unlocked. So does anyone know if there is a way to perform this with a photo that would be saved on a network drive that he has access to?

Comment: Yes, they are called executables, scripts, macros...

Comment: I understand that much... I was more looking for a method or hopefully someone who already had a batch file created to do so. I searched and couldn't find one on my own.

Comment: Then you should have phrased it as such. Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need a batch script that changes the appropriate values in the registry, and get the user to click the file.
I didn't test it, but i found something you can [try](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/windows-nt-2000-xp/threads/65339/changing-a-background-in-a-batch-script#post914468):

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Written by Eric Husband
:: 7/10/2009
:: copies the wallpaper from a location into the proper directory and as the proper file name. DO NOT CHANGE THE DESTINATION FILE NAME.
copy "\\ehusband-x1\ERIC\wallpaper1.bmp" "C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\wallpaper1.bmp"
:: Adds the necessary Registry values, in case this person is using a System Wallpaper. If they've already customized their wallpaper, the following lines are not necessary. They won't hurt though.
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V Wallpaper /T REG_SZ /F /D "C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\wallpaper1.bmp"
:: Change the last number in the following line to a 0 if you want to center the bitmap on the desktop. Change the last number in the following line to a 2 if you want to stretch the bitmap vertically and horizontally to fit the desktop.
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V WallpaperStyle /T REG_SZ /F /D 2
:: Change the last number in the following line to a 0 to not tile the image; setting it to a 1 Tiles it.
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V TileWallpaper /T REG_SZ /F /D 0
:: The following line refreshes the desktop.
%SystemRoot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
:: The following line Locks the workstation.
%SystemRoot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

Comment: Please expand, link only answers are not a good format for a Q&A site.

Comment: I was able to get my answer from this link. Thank you Crimson.